# How to base64-decode a Numpy array (Python) in Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, python, numpy, kotlin, base64

Of course, there are way better/secure options to transfer/store data, but let's assume we are bound to this representation.

The following Python code converts a Numpy array to Base64:

```
import base64
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3], dtype=np.float32)
print(base64.b64encode(arr).decode("ascii"))
```

Output:

```
zcyMP83MDEAzM1NA
```

Using Kotlin I'd like to convert back to the original `float` values:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.DataInputStream
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val buffer = Base64.getDecoder().decode("zcyMP83MDEAzM1NA")
    val ds = DataInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(buffer))
    val arr = FloatArray(buffer.size / 4)
    for (i in arr.indices) {
        arr[i] = ds.readFloat()
    }
    println(arr.contentToString())
}
```

The output, however, is not as expected, i.e., `[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]`, but the following instead:

```
[-4.28967904E8, -4.2791936E8, 4.17524E-8]
```

What's my mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, palying around, I'm pretty sure has to do with endianess, consider:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3], dtype=np.float32)
>>> arr
array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3], dtype=float32)
>>> arr.byteswap()
array([-4.2896790e+08, -4.2791936e+08,  4.1752401e-08], dtype=float32)
```

So on the Python side you could use:

```
base64.b64encode(arr.byteswap())
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. `print(base64.b64encode(arr.byteswap()).decode("ascii"))` in Python outputs `P4zMzUAMzM1AUzMz`. Decoding this in Kotlin correctly results in `[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]`. To do this modification in Kotlin instead of Python, using `com.google.common.io.LittleEndianDataInputStream` works nicely: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/d46c98278c78d3967ac37f4835e712ac